# Integral of a product of quasi-gaussians

Tags: integration, statistics

I have to calculate this integral ($\Lambda$ is a symmetric matrix and $\vec a$ a constant vector).

$$\int ds_1...ds_{N_c-1}\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N_{c}-1}\left[-\frac{1}{2}s_{i}^{2}(\Lambda)_{ii}-s_{i}\left(\sum_{j=i+1}^{N_{c}-1}s_{j,lm}\left(\Lambda\right)_{ij}+(\vec{a})_{i}\right)\right]\right) H_3(s_1)$$

If I fix a $s_k$ I have an integral with a function of the type $\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}Ax^2+Bx\right)$. But then it's difficult to integrate for the rest of the variables....

Have you some hint?

Edit: Solution found with Feynman Integrals!